# How can I set a uniform button border color in html?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button

I want to border for my button to be black, but Chrome automatically formats the button to have a lighter left and top border, even though I have specified

```
border-color:black;
```

This is how my button looks. Notice how the left and top borders are grey instead of black.
[image: my button]

How can I stop Chrome from automatically lightening those borders?

Comment: `border-style: solid`, or just `border: black`?

Comment: `border-style:solid` did it perfectly, thank you!